# Why python3.7 sys.path doesn't contain PYTHONPATH where as python2.7 does?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, ubuntu-16.04, python-3.7

sys.path for python2.7 and python3.7 differ on the same machine.
I understand python specific directories will be different

PYTHONPATH is set to '/opt/manu/python/lib'

For python2.7
`['', '/opt/manu/python/lib', '/usr/lib/python2.7', '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages']`

For python3.7
`['', '/usr/lib/python37.zip', '/usr/lib/python3.7', '/usr/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python3.7/dist-packages']`

I am unable to understand why `/opt/manu/python/lib` is not a part of sys.path in case of python3.7

To add more I am trying this using sudo python and sudo python3.7, if that helps

Is that expected?If yes why?
If not can you please guide me on what I am missing here?

Comment: Why would you expect them to be the same? the documentation for `sys.path` says `A list of strings that specifies the search path for modules.` Why would you expect python 3 and python2 would have the same module dirs?

Comment: A list of strings that specifies the search path for modules. Initialized from the environment variable PYTHONPATH, plus an installation-dependent default.

I understand they will be different but PYTHONPATH should be present right?

Comment: @ChrisDoyle updated my question so that it makes more sense

Comment: Ah sorry i read it as you are not able to understand why they are different. Does your sudo possibly change your enviroment varilable for PYTHONPATH?

Comment: @ChrisDoyle no it was my bad, I made it confusing.If it does, it should do so for both python2.7 and python3.7 right